# Find url and replace?

Tags: javascript, jquery, safari-extension

Is there any way I can do this... user presses a button, button finds all urls, `example.com`, and replaces it with `sub.example.com`?

Comment: Find URLs where... in anchors, images, text nodes?

Comment: I only need it to replace a tags: `a href="example"` with `a href="sub.example".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
$('#replace-button').click(function() { 
    $('a[href="example.com"]').attr('href', 'sub.example.com');
});
```

To clarify, this is using the CSS attribute selector.  The example finds `a` tags who have an `href` value of exactly 'example.com' - if your links had `http://www.` (or something like that) in front of them, this would not match them.  There are more variations of the attribute selector, refer to http://css-tricks.com/attribute-selectors/ for examples.

Comment: Your fiddle should be updated with a correctly functioning example.

Comment: Ah thank you very much. Could it be set up as onload, so that when you load it changes the links?

Comment: Change `$('#replace-button').click(` to `$(document).ready(` and it will do so.

Comment: @Charlie, his example would work but he put http:// in the a tag but used [href="example.com"] instead of [href="http://\example.com"] (the backslash is there to escape the link right here.)

Comment: @Nathan Anderson, this version is a lot cleaner.

Answer (score 4):

If you want to replace all `a.href` attributes:

```
$(function(){
    $('#buttonID').click(function(){
        $('a').each(function(){
            var newHref =  $(this).attr('href').replace('example.com','sub.example.com');
            $(this).attr('href',newHref);
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: I'm not a javascript guy at all, but here's what I tried.. http://jsfiddle.net/vaFYM/

Comment: @charlie Just remove the 2nd and 7th lines